# Duration of setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, duration

I created a simple function which counting value from 0 to some value during 3 sec.

Here is fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ar6akv5z/ and snippet:

```js
var number = document.querySelector('.number');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    counting(number, 2500);
})

function counting(elem, value) {
 var count = 0;
 var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  if (++count == value) clearInterval(timerId);
  elem.innerHTML = count;
 }, 3000/value);
}
```

```html
<span class="number">0</span>
<button>Go</button>
```

But the duration of the function takes longer than 3 seconds.
Can you explain me why it is happend or show me my mistake.

Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: `++count`? Is this valid JavaScript?

Comment: Try with changing `document.querySelector('.number');` to `document.querySelector('.number')[0];` . The same for button.

Comment: @yuriy636 yes - [prefix increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Comment: Technically, the `setTimeout`/`setInterval` functions don't run something in _exactly_ the timeout you give but rather _schedule it_ to be run then. The difference is that since JS is single threaded, something else might be being processed already, so the timeout/interval-ed thing would be put on the queue

Comment: @Miloshio that won't change anything. `querySelector` returns a maximum of one element

Comment: @Miloshio: That will make it break, rather than working but just not having the timing the OP wants.

Comment: @Vld: JavaScript is not single-threaded. Browsers run one main UI JavaScript thread (and as many web workers as you want).

Comment: @RobM. yes, but `elem.innerHTML` inside `counting` function is not going to work on HTML collections.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, yes - you are right. But that's what I meant - your JS code is, usually, running in a single thread. It's however shorter to just say "single threaded" instead of dipping into the specifics.

Comment: @Miloshio `querySelector` does not return an HTML Collection, it returns a single DOM node.

Comment: To all folks and to Q poster: sorry, my bad. I've mixed `querySelector` with `querySelectorAll`

Comment: The problem is that with `setInterval` you set the *minimum* time before to call the callback. `3000/2500` is `1.2` milliseconds and I assume the browser simply decides to take `2` milliseconds instead. So in total your timer takes 2 * 2500 = 5 seconds.

Comment: @Vld: To get around that, I usually say "Since the browser runs your code on one main UI thread." (Because this myth that JavaScript is single-threaded is, in my view, pernicious. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see, that's definitely short and accurate enough. Thanks for the tip, I'll make sure to spread the word :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum interval of a timer is subject to [an algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timers) specified is the HTML5 spec (originally it was in the now-defunct timers spec), to keep timers from firing too rapidly. When a timer schedules a timer (which is essentially what `setInterval` does), once the nesting reaches five, if the timer interval requested is < 4ms, it's set to 4ms:

> 7. If nesting level is greater than 5, and timeout is less than 4, then increase timeout to 4.

Since you're telling it to count up by 1 each time the timer fires, and it quite quickly starts only firing every 4ms (at best), it takes 4 * 2500 = 10000ms (10 seconds) to finish.

You can see this average delay in the updated snippet below, which replaces the counter with the average time between callbacks:

```js
if (!Date.now) {
  Date.now = function() {
    return +new Date();
  };
}
var number = document.querySelector('.number');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var sum = 0;
var last = null;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    counting(number, 2500);
})

function counting(elem, value) {
 var count = 0;
  last = Date.now();
 var timerId = setInterval(function() {
   var now = Date.now();
   sum += now - last;
   last = now;
  if (++count == value) clearInterval(timerId);
  elem.innerHTML = sum / count;
 }, 3000/value);
}
```

```html
<span class="number">0</span>
<button>Go</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a minimum delay enforced by `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Minimummaximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting)

> **Reasons for delays longer than specified**
>
> Nested timeouts forced to >=4ms
>
> Historically browsers implement setTimeout() "clamping": successive setTimeout() calls with delay smaller than the "minimum delay" limit are forced to use at least the minimum delay. The minimum delay, DOM_MIN_TIMEOUT_VALUE, is 4 ms (stored in a preference in Firefox: dom.min_timeout_value), with a DOM_CLAMP_TIMEOUT_NESTING_LEVEL of 5.
>
> In fact, 4 ms is specified by the HTML5 spec and is consistent across browsers released in 2010 and onward. Prior to (Firefox 5.0 / Thunderbird 5.0 / SeaMonkey 2.2), the minimum timeout value for nested timeouts was 10 ms.

So even though you're specifying `3000/2500 = 1.2` as the interval time, it's acting as if you'd used `4` as the interval time.